# What is the difference between expo prebuild and expo eject?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

I am in need of a more sophisticated notifications api/server. My app depends heavily on notifications and expo doesn't have much notification feature except the basic ones. I want to use an open source library called [Notifee](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/installation#expo-support). But they tell me to prebuild my expo app in order to use it. Is prebuilding the same as ejecting?

Comment: you can also use development builds for this: https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ - prebuild is what runs on EAS Build to generate the native project directories before building. you can also run it locally if you want to build locally or make direct modifications to your native projects

Comment: @brentvatne Does prebuilding affect my original work in any way??

Comment: https://expo.fyi/prebuild-cleanup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notifee library depends on the native modules which are not working with the standard Expo Go App development environment.

Before Expo SDK 42, It was required to eject to be able to add native modules. Starting with Expo SDK 42, you can add native modules without Ejecting.

To compile native modules, Expo provides the option to compile your custom Expo Go app with your custom native module ( Notifee) embedded.

With Expo Go Custom App, you still have same Expo Developer experience as the norm with the extra capabilities to add any custom library.

You can refer to this video where Expo Founder shows the process to compile a custom Expo App with native modules embedded - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w&t=25s

Comment: I have been on your answer for about two weeks now. My eas build keeps failing and I haven't even gone halfway through the video. Just running eas build --profile development --platform android. It fails everytime, and the solutions online to fix it unfortunately didn't work for me. I have asked questions recently on stackoverflow but no one has answers even on expo github itself. Its so frustrating now. Please could you look at my questions? I can't mark this answer as correct till I'm sure it actually works for expo managed workflow.

Comment: It seems your personal assistance, Check the way to contact me on my StackOverflow profile page